# Unable to display URL link properly in data table

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint-2010

I am supposed to display title, name, content, and URL in a data table, my following codes below works, but it is showing 6 columns instead of 4 columns. I used the hyperlink because I want to bind the link into my data table. For every search results, i want to display the results in the data table. What is wrong with my for loop? Why am I getting 3 columns of URL? I want only 1 URL column where I am able to click the link of a related content.

```
    protected void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPWeb objCurrentWeb;
        SPList objSSList;
        String searchWord = searchBox.Text;
        int intMemberIndex = 0;
        /*WebRequest objWebRequest;
        WebResponse objWebResponse;
        Stream objResponseStream;
        StreamReader objStreamReader;*/


        objCurrentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        objSSList = objCurrentWeb.Lists["Sales Materials"];

        try
        {

            DataTable result = new DataTable();

            result.Columns.Add("Title");
            result.Columns.Add("Name");
            result.Columns.Add("Content");
            result.Columns.Add("Link");


            foreach (SPListItem objSSListItem in objSSList.Items)
            {
                String title = objSSListItem["Title"].ToString();
                String name = objSSListItem["Name"].ToString();
                String content = objSSListItem["Content Type"].ToString();


                if (title.ToUpper().Contains(searchWord.ToUpper()) || name.ToUpper().Contains(searchWord.ToUpper()) || content.ToUpper().Contains(searchWord.ToUpper()))
                {
                    //assign the list item ID to the intMemberIndex variable and exit
                    intMemberIndex = objSSListItem.ID;
                    String url = "http:google.com/" + objSSListItem.Url;

                    HyperLinkField hfield = new HyperLinkField();
                    hfield.HeaderText = "Link";
                    hfield.NavigateUrl = url;
                    hfield.DataTextField = "Link";
                    resultGrid.Columns.Add(hfield);

                    result.Rows.Add(title, name, content,url);      
                }
            }
           this.resultGrid.DataSource = result;
           this.resultGrid.Visible = true;
            this.resultGrid.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new column to your datagrid on every pass of your for loop where the if condition is true in this line:

```
resultGrid.Columns.Add(hfield);
```

If you post your datatable markup too, you'll get a more specific solution.